# Getting Exception error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot find context with specified id"} with Chromedriver 2.29

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting below exception when I am trying to do 
`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button/span[text()='Cancel']/../following-sibling::button/span[text()='Ok']")).size()!=0`.

Though I am using `driver.findElements` at other places also, but its failing here.

```
Chrome: 58x version
ChromeDriver: 2.29 version
Selenium: 2.52 version
```

**Error trace-back:**

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: **unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot find context with specified id"}**
>     (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 5.44 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
>   System info: host: 'Iaglab2', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_75'
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//button/span[text()='Cancel']/../following-sibling::button/span[text()='Ok']}
>   Session ID: 44c20fabdca96942ee2f9de6fc7d3c23
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=WIN8_1, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\hravi\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9172_8986, chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233)}, networkConnectionEnabled=false, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=58.0.3029.110, pageLoadStrategy=normal, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, hasTouchScreen=false, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]

Comment: Can you check whether element is inside frame or not ?

Comment: Yes, Element is inside frame but I am already on that frame and performing other actions before its getting failed here.
And same code is working on other machine with same configuration

Comment: i'm getting the same exact issue, not consistently though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a bug with Chrome driver.

[Chrome driver bug -1224](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1224)

But this bug was fixed for chrome driver v2.21. But we are again facing similar issue. I am facing same issue with 2.30 and even with latest 2.32 versions.

Comment: The OP's error is NOT the problem that was fixed with Chromedriver bug 1224.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could "ignore" this exception, so instead of except NoSuchElementException:, you could generalize all exceptions

```
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath,driver):
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
except: #All exceptions are handeled here
    return False
return True
```

It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

go to.... File>Invalidate Caches>Invalidate Caches and Restart ...

Comment: where exactly ?